# Apache 403 after /var/www backup

Tags: wordpress, apache, rhel

I'm running a WordPress site on a RHEL server and I do backup every week for the WP MySQL database and the /var/www folder:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p******** blog -l -F > /bak/blog.sql
tar -jcpv -f /bak/www.tar.bz2 /var/www
```

The latest backup was done at 6 a.m. (UTC +8) this morning and I upgraded WP to 3.9 at 7. Some features were not compatible with 3.9, so I decided to roll back. I restored the database and the folder:

```
mysql -uroot -p blog < /bak/blog.sql
tar -jxv -f /bak/www.tar.bz2 -C /
```

and then the site gave me a 403. I restarted Apache and rebooted the server but it didn't help. The site was running before I upgraded WP, so I think the conf.s are the same before and after the backup/restore, therefore the problem might not be there. My homepage is redirect to my.si.te/blog/, and I can't visit a pure index.html at my.si.te/test/ (/var/www/html/test/) either. It's the same message: You don't have permission to access /(blog/test) on this server.

```
[Mon Apr 21 08:42:48 2014] [crit] [client 144.*.*.*] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/html/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
[Mon Apr 21 08:42:56 2014] [crit] [client 157.*.*.*] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/html/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
[Mon Apr 21 08:42:58 2014] [crit] [client 178.*.*.*] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/html/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable, referer: http://my.si.te
```

What would be the problem and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Are the files back on disk in the correct places (I don't recognise all of your `tar` flags) and with the correct owners and permissions? Do you have SELinux enabled, and have you still got the correct httpd flags on your restored content? Is there anything specific in /var/log/httpd/error_log?

Comment: @Rup thanks for your prompt reply! Yes, the owners and permissions stay the same before and after restore, and i'm not sure what httpd 'flags' means... the .htaccess or part of httpd.conf?

Comment: Sorry, had forgotten the correct term: it's an SELinux 'type'. If you are using SELinux then you'll need to make sure that all of the restored files have an httpd security context type which I think is `httpd_sys_content_t`, i.e. `chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_content_t /var/www`. But that's only necessary if you're using SELinux - are you?

Comment: Millions of thanks! I turned off SELinux and the site is back! Then I turned it on and tried the command you offered — it works too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight way (reboot required): vim /etc/selinux/config (RedHat/CentOS), and set

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

and reboot. Or keep the selinux with a warning msg (reboot needed still), vim selinux config, and set

```
SELINUX=permissive
```

Or an immediate command would be (temporary effect):

```
echo 0 > /selinux/enforce
# echo 1 > /selinux/enforce (put selinux back)
```

I choose to give the web files a pass and leave selinux on:

```
chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_content_t /var/www
```

If a Ghost blogging platform (blog.si.te) is running, an extra line may be needed:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```